# How to react: asking for clarification in an answer?

Tags: discussion

Unfortunately, I've failed to find an exact case for now. A new user started an answer by asking for clarification - something that would be considered NNA normally. However, the same answer included a (not even bad) attempt to answer the question. What would be a proper reaction? It's not an NNA as a whole, but a part of it should be a comment. Should I just comment (what to comment), flag for moderator attention, or do something in the middle in such cases?

Comment: Down vote, flag as NAA and move on. Do not flag for a moderator. Moderators won't judge the (in)correctness of content.

Comment: What would "NNA" be?

Comment: @rene The problem is that, unfortunately, it *is* an answer, just starting with a question

Comment: I wouldn't flag as NAA if there is an attempt to answer. A comment however would be the case here. Telling the poster to be more assertive with their answers. Otherwise, if they are uncertain they should comment.

Comment: I've commented on some of those with something like "Are you asking for clarification or answering the Question?". If they respond, I've asked them to remove the asking part. Sometimes it works..